# Defining AspNetCoreHostingModel in csproj throws Failed to start 'npm' exception

Tags: asp.net-core

The ASP.NET Core 2.2 update has this new `AspNetCoreHostingModel` property that can be set to `InProcess` or `OutOfProccess`. If I add the property in the `csproj` and it doesn't matter to which option I set, I get the following error:

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:
[1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: (there are some 20 paths before this last one);C:\Program Files\nodejs;
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
```

The path to `npm` is already stated there, so what else can be the problem?

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue. I have not found anything yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added "AspNetCoreModule" to PropertyGroup and it worked.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/12/04/asp-net-core-2-2-available-today/

Comment: I don't host my app on Azure, that's why I skipped that par, but now I'm getting a `The transform web.config task failed unexpectedly`

Comment: when i add the following line 
<AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
I get "The transform web.config task failed unexpectedly"  error
Do you know why?

Comment: Not an answer, but possible next steps: Not sure, you might have to ask here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio